# How to reliably detect the open of every trade

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am writing a Pine Script strategy that needs to detect when every new trade is opened.

After some experimentation, I found that the following approach **almost** solves the problem:

```
var string lastEntryId = ''
var int lastEntryTime = 0

if strategy.opentrades > 0
    int _lastIndex = strategy.opentrades - 1
    string _entryId = strategy.opentrades.entry_id(_lastIndex)
    int _entryTime = strategy.opentrades.entry_time(_lastIndex)
    if _entryTime != lastEntryTime and _entryId != lastEntryId
        lastEntryId := _entryId
        lastEntryTime := _entryTime
        log.info('New trade opened: ' + _entryId + ' ' + str.tostring(_entryTime))
```

If the above snippet is appended to any strategy, it should log the opening of each trade. However, it doesn't detect trades that open on the last bar (i.e. the real-time bar).

In contrast, the Strategy Tester includes these last-minute trades in its result set, so it is sometimes not possible to reconcile the statistics from my strategy with the Strategy Tester performance summary data.

Is there any way for my script to reliably detect when all trades are opened, including those that open on the last bar?

Comment: You will open a new trade when, well, you do a, ie.: `strategy.entry()` or its equivalent. Why not register when they happened and build that list as you go?

Comment: Thanks @karatedog, that's a good suggestion. Unfortunately, I need this for a library script function that will be shared by many strategies, so I don't have direct control over the calling of strategy.entry().

Comment: On a second thought what I suggested is not a good idea :D You can fire a strategy.entry() and Pine can ignore it if, say, it would start the 2nd trade, but you have set up your strategy() to allow only 1.